# How Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator could be properly injected into service?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to inject a validator class into my service.

My service.yml config:

```
validator_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Validator\ValidatorService
        argument: ['@validator']
```

But insted I got an error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Service\Validator\ValidatorService::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator, none given...
```

How can I properly inject a validator class into my service? What principles should I guide next time, to find proper name for injection (may be some tutorial, that I missed in symfony's docs)?

Thanks

Comment: Use the Symfony console to list all services `php bin/console container:debug`

Comment: @JimL  thanks. Right command is debug:container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is "arguments", not "argument".

Comment: thank you. This is so stupid mistake. I was watching for any typo in services.yml file for thousands times and haven't found any... Gotta buy new glasses...